# I need to highlight a listbox element that is referred to by another element

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to do the following. I have a listBox with a DataTemplate that is bound to a list of objects.

I also have another element that is bound to an object. that object contains a property that is a reference to one of the elements in the listbox.

The DataTemplate for the ListBox has a border and I want to make an extra thick border around the list item that is referred to by the other object.

I have been playing around with triggers and such, but I can't seem to get my head around how to solve this problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you sure you mean *WCF* and not *WPF?*

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. good catch. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check out [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx). You can select which datatemplate to use based on the bound object's property.

Comment: I'm not sure that will work, because is is not the property of the list item that I need to make the decision based on. it is the property of the other non-list item elsewhere. Unless I am missing a trick somewher, I am still learning the subtleties of WPF

Comment: could you create a property on the list item, then update that property based on the other non-list item?

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid that, because the highlight is really a effect it being referred to by the other object, not an attribute of the listitem itself